# tic tac toe how to keep the game on until win or tie

Tags: javascript

I am writing a tic tac toe game using `JavaScript(no DOM)` in console.
    I started by doing only one player game and only with 'X'. When the player chooses the row index and the column index and then it store inside an array(Move), but I'm stuck, the player able to do only one move, and that's it. I really dont know what to do from there.

```
       // Variables

    let playerName, playerMove = [],
        playerShape, boardGame;

    // Functions

    // Get And Check Name 

    function getCheckName() {
        let name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name");
        while (name == null || !isNaN(name) || name == ' ') {
            alert("Numbers And Spaces Not Allowed");
            name = prompt("Please Enter Your Name");
        }
        alert("Welcome " + name);
        return name;
    }
    playerName = getCheckName();
    playerShape = 'X';

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // // Get Row And Col 

    function getRowAndCol() {
        let row, col, rowAndColArr = [];
        row = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter A Row"));
        while (row > 2 || row < 0 || row === null || isNaN(row)) {
            alert("Not a Valid Row number");
            row = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter A Row"));
        }
        rowAndColArr[rowAndColArr.length] = row;

        col = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter A Col"));
        while (col > 2 || col < 0 || col === null || isNaN(col)) {
            alert("Not a Valid Col number");
            col = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter A Col"));
        }
        rowAndColArr[rowAndColArr.length] = col;
        return rowAndColArr;
    }
    playerMove = getRowAndCol();

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Board Game 

    boardGame = [
        ["_", "_", "_"],
        ["_", "_", "_"],
        ["_", "_", "_"]
    ];

    function boardFn(board, move) {
        for (let rw = 0; rw < board.length; rw++) {
            for (let cl = 0; cl < board[rw].length; cl++) {
                while (rw === move[0] && cl === move[1] && board[rw][cl] === "_") {
                    board[rw][cl] = playerShape;
                }
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
    let keepGame = boardFn(boardGame, playerMove);

    do {

    } while (condition);

    console.log(checkWinner());

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Check Win

    function equal3(a, b, c) {
        return (a == b && b == c && a != "_");
    };

    function checkWinner() {
        let winner = null;

        // Win In Horizontal

        for (let rw = 0; rw < 3; rw++) {
            if (equal3(boardGame[rw][0], boardGame[rw][1], boardGame[rw][2])) {
                winner = boardGame[rw][0];
                alert(playerName + " You Won line");
            }
        }

        // Win In Vertical

        for (let cl = 0; cl < 3; cl++) {
            if (equal3(boardGame[0][cl], boardGame[1][cl], boardGame[2][cl])) {
                winner = boardGame[cl][0];
                alert(playerName + " You Won col");
            }
        }

        // Win In Diagonal

        if (equal3(boardGame[0][0], boardGame[1][1], boardGame[2][2])) {
            winner = boardGame[0][0];
            alert(playerName + " You Won diagonal");
        }

        // Win In Diagonal (Other Way)

        if (equal3(boardGame[2][0], boardGame[1][1], boardGame[0][2])) {
            winner = boardGame[2][0];
            alert(playerName + " You Won digonal other");
        }
        return winner;
    }
```

Comment: It is not so clear how you are getting user input in the above code. Using prompt? Can you share the complete code so that it would be better to have a better understanding of your state?

Comment: yes, of course i will edit again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated code for two players

```
var board = [
    ["_", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "_"],
    ["_", "_", "_"]
];

//This function will prompt and get user name

function getName(player) {
    let name = prompt("Please Enter " + player + " Name");
    while (name == null || !isNaN(name) || name == ' ') {
        alert("Numbers And Spaces Not Allowed");
        name = prompt("Please Enter " + player + " Name");
    }
    alert("Welcome, " + name + "!");
    return name;
}

//This function will prompt and get row and column from player

function getRowAndCol(player) {
    let row, col, rowAndColArr = [];
    row = parseInt(prompt(player + "! Please Enter A Row"));
    while (row > 2 || row < 0 || row === null || isNaN(row)) {
        alert("Not a Valid Row number");
        row = parseInt(prompt(player + "! Please Enter A Row"));
    }
    rowAndColArr[rowAndColArr.length] = row;

    col = parseInt(prompt(player + "! Please Enter A Col"));
    while (col > 2 || col < 0 || col === null || isNaN(col)) {
        alert("Not a Valid Col number");
        col = parseInt(prompt(player + "! Please Enter A Col"));
    }
    rowAndColArr[rowAndColArr.length] = col;

    //This block will check if the given box already marked. If so it will prompt for the move.
    if (board[rowAndColArr[0]][rowAndColArr[1]] !== "_") {
        alert("Already marked on the given box. Please Enter different row and column.!");
        return getRowAndCol(player)
    }

    return rowAndColArr;
}

//This function will update the position with the given shape according to the move

function boardFn(board, move, shape) {
    for (let rw = 0; rw < board.length; rw++) {
        for (let cl = 0; cl < board[rw].length; cl++) {
            while (rw === move[0] && cl === move[1] && board[rw][cl] === "_") {
                board[rw][cl] = shape;
            }
        }
    }
}

//This function will check if it is tie

function isTie() {
      for (let rw = 0; rw < board.length; rw++) {
        for (let cl = 0; cl < board[rw].length; cl++) {
            if( board[rw][cl] === "_" ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
      }
      return true;
}



//These functions will check whether the current player win or not

function equal3(a, b, c) {
    return (a == b && b == c && a != "_");
};

function checkWinner(player) {
    let winner = null;

    // Win In Horizontal

    for (let rw = 0; rw < 3; rw++) {
        if (equal3(board[rw][0], board[rw][1], board[rw][2])) {
            winner = board[rw][0];
            alert(player + " You Won line");
        }
    }

    // Win In Vertical

    for (let cl = 0; cl < 3; cl++) {
        if (equal3(board[0][cl], board[1][cl], board[2][cl])) {
            winner = board[cl][0];
            alert(player + " You Won col");
        }
    }

    // Win In Diagonal

    if (equal3(board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2])) {
        winner = board[0][0];
        alert(player + " You Won diagonal");
    }

    // Win In Diagonal (Other Way)

    if (equal3(board[2][0], board[1][1], board[0][2])) {
        winner = board[2][0];
        alert(player + " You Won digonal other");
    }
    return winner;
}

var player1 = getName("Player 1") // getting player 1 name
alert(player1 + "! Your shape is 'X'");
var player2 = getName("Player 2") // getting player 2 name
alert(player2 + "! Your shape is 'O'");

// Variables to maintain current players and shape
var currentPlayer = ""
var currentShape = ""

// This block will get and validate moves until we get a winner
while (true) {

    // This block will switch player after a move

    if (currentPlayer == "") {
        currentPlayer = player1;
        currentShape = "X";
    } else if (currentPlayer == player1) {
        currentPlayer = player2;
        currentShape = "O";
    } else {
        currentPlayer = player1;
        currentShape = "X";
    }

    var move = getRowAndCol(currentPlayer);
    boardFn(board, move, currentShape);

    var status = "";
    for (var i in board) {
        for (var j in board[i]) {
            status += board[i][j] + " ";
        }
        status += "\n";
    }
    console.log(status);
    console.log("-------------------------------");

    if (checkWinner(currentPlayer)) {
            break;
    } else if (isTie()) {
            alert("Game tied.!")
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes it works thank you, can you please explain what you did ? and maybe give me some tips on how to do 2 players ? (After each move i want the player to see where he put his 'X' so where i need to console log the boardGame

Comment: I have just filled out the while loop you left. You have a method checkWinner() which would return winner if he wins else undefined. So, I have just repeatedly called getRowAndCol & boardFn methods until we get a winner. The loop will break once we have a winner.

For printing out the board after each move you could simply console log boardGame variable in the while loop end. Let me update the answer if possible.

And about the second player, you may need to tweak the boardFn method a bit. May be pass the playerShape as param. Give it a try. You can always reach out for help here.

Comment: @OfekEzra I have updated my answer so that it would console log the board after each move. Cheers.

PS:- If you find the answer helpful you can accept and upvote the answer so that it would help others who need the same stuff.

Comment: works great! , thank you so much you helped me a lot . i will give a try for two players .

Comment: im am still stuck, do i need another array for the second player ? , and about playerShape, how to alternate between 'X' and 'O' ?

Comment: @OfekEzra I have update the code in my answer above and commented on the code blocks itself. Go through them. If you still find any difficulties, you can get back here. Accept and upvote the answer if you find it helpful. Cheers.!

Comment: thanks you so much , i have a hard time on how to break those problem down to piece, i recentally joined codewars do you think by practicing codewars i will ge better ?? do you have any tips

Comment: It will come with practice. You can look out for problems to practice  and solve in many places. Codewars is one such. You will find it helpful. Keep on practicing and you will get better in it. And anytime you are stuck and need help you can reach out to the community. It seems like you are new to the community. Do you know that you can even upvote comments in the thread? :wink

Comment: yes i am new her , i tried to upvote you solution but its said  that i dont have enough reputation, and thank you for the tips

Comment: sorry bother you again , i tried to add tie condition to checkwinner() function like this: for (let i in board){for (let j in board) { if (winner == null&& board[i][j] !== "_") { alert("Its a tie) }}; , but i doesnt seem to work

Comment: @OfekEzra You would need to check if game ties after every move. I have added a method to check if tied and called after each move in the answer above. Check that out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559213/how-to-fix-reset-button-problem-in-js-dom . hey man i have another problem if you can help